# Packaging a Spring managed Axis2 web service client

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jar, apache-axis

I've created a web service client using Axis2. I would like to package the client into a jar, so I can use it in several other projects. The client uses the Axis2 WS-Security module 'rampart'. This module, rampart.mar (not a typo!) has to be present on the Axis 'repository path', in a directory called 'modules'. The client also requires a security policy file, policy.xml. The locations of these last two are injected via Spring, but as they are not subject to change, I would like to package them into the jar.

If you inject a File object like:

```
<bean id="webserviceStubFactory" class="com.company.WebserviceStubFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:policy.xml"/>
</bean>
```

it will work just fine when running/testing the project directly. However, when you package it into a jar, you get

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [policy.xml] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/path/to/webservice-0.8.jar!/policy.xml`

This is a well known Spring 'problem': the constructor-arg is resolved into a Spring ClasspathResource instance and it doesn't support getFile(), because File instances cannot refer to something inside a jar. The solution to this is pretty simple: change the constructor to take a Resource instead of a file and use the InputStream directly. However, this doesn't work for the Axis2 repository path, as I can only specify the full path to the repository and the Axis2 internals figure out where the rampart.mar is located.

So, the question basically boils down to: is it possible to use Spring to inject a path inside a jar (even if it's only /) and have other libraries read from that path as if it were a regular filesystem? I'm guessing it isn't, but I would like to be sure, before installing external 'axis repositories' on the dev/test/production environments and having several copies of the rampart.mar lying around.

Answer (score 1):

There's only so much that Spring can do to hide the inconsistencies of the underlying JavaSE API. The various `getXYZ` methods on the `Resource` interface come with caveats in the documentation, e.g. for `getFile()`:

```
Throws:
    IOException - if the resource cannot be resolved as absolute file path, 
    i.e. if the resource is not available in a file system
```

A resource inside a JAR is not "on a filesystem", and so this will never work.

In your case you're going to have to work around Axis2's requirement to operate on files, but manually making sure a file exists. In other words, use `Resource.getInputStream()` to extract the content of the JAR resource and copy it to a temporary `File` on the local filesystem, then pass *that* `File` to Axis2.

Comment: The problem is that Axis2 requires a /path/to/ to be given, while it searches for /path/to/modules/rampart.mar. There isn't any file to read in that case. On the other hand, passing a reference to the policy.xml inside the jar works just fine, as I can pass that one as a Resource.

In the Axis2 sources I see that it constructs a full URL to find the .mar modules in the Repository, but for some reason it doesn't work. As the amount of time I can spend on this problem is limited, I will probably opt for the ugly solution and just include a rampart.mar in every project that uses this one. :/